# proof of $-\ln\left(2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(kx)}{k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

There is an identity that I have seen pop up in a few questions on this stackexchange, and I was wondering what proof there is for it. It goes something like this:
$$-\ln\left(2\sin\left(\frac x2\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\cos(kx)}{k}$$

Again, my question is:

*How do you prove this identity?*

Comment: Equivalent to $$\sin(\frac{x}{2}) = \prod^{\infty}_{k=1} e^{\frac{1}{k}\cos(kx)}$$

Comment: how about expanding both sides?

Answer (score 6):

$-\dfrac{\cos(kx)}k=$ real of $-\dfrac{e^{ikx}}k$

As $\ln(1-h)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{h^r}r,$

$\sum-\dfrac{e^{ikx}}k=\ln\left[1-e^{ix}\right]$

$=\ln(e^{ix/2})+\ln(e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2})$

$=ix/2+\ln(i\cdot2\sin x/2)$

$=ix/2+\ln i+\ln(2\sin x/2)$

$i=e^{i\pi/2}\implies\ln(i)=i\pi/2$

Comment: Where does the second line come from?

Comment: @user7530,Please find the edited version

Comment: So the identity only holds true for real $x$?

Comment: @nbubis, What if $-\pi<\dfrac x 2<0\implies\sin \dfrac x2<0$

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see a
$\cos(kx)$ or
$\sin(kx)$
I automatically think of
the real or imaginary part
of $e^{-kx}$.

So, let
$f(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{k}
$.
$f'(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ie^{ikx}
=\frac{ie^{ix}}{1-e^{ix}}
$.

At this stage,
I try to integrate
$\frac{e^{ax}}{1-e^{ax}}$,
so that I can later
set $a = i$.

Being lazy,
I throw it at
Wolfram's integrator
and get
$\frac{-\ln(e^{ax}-1)}{a}
$.
I check that
yes,
this is correct.

Putting $a=i$,
I get
$\int \frac{ie^{ix}dx}{1-e^{ix}}
=\frac{-i\ln(e^{-ix}-1)}{i}
=-\ln(e^{-ix}-1)
$.

Looking at that result,
I get annoyed at myself
for not immediately using
$-\ln(1-x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}
$.

At this point,
I stop and
give this to you to finish,
leaving you the task
of getting the $\ln$
of that complex expression
and separating the
real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1):

### Here's is my proof :D

---

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(kx)}{k}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ikx}}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{k}\right)=$$
$$\frac{-1}{2}\left(\ln(1-e^{ix})+\ln(1-e^{-ix}\right)=$$
$$\frac{-1}{2}\ln \left (2-2\cos(x)\right)=$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln[(2\sin(x/2))^2]=-{\ln[2\sin(x/2)]}$$

$$\boxed{\therefore \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(kx)}{k}=\ln[2\sin(x/2)]}$$

$$\large{\text{Note Section:}}$$
$$cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$$